# R: Incorrect number of probabilities error when running Markov Chain simulation

Tags: r, simulation, markov-chains

This is from chapter 9 of "Analyzing Baseball Data with R," attempting to simulate runs scored in a half inning;

```
simulate<-function(P,R,start=1){
s<-start; path<-NULL; runs<-0
while(s<25){
s.new<-sample(1:25, 1, prob=P[s, ])
path<-c(path, s.new)
runs<-runs + R[s, s.new]
s<-s.new
}
runs
}
```

this is pretty much identical to the code in the book. When I attempt to run it with the following code, I get the following error;

> RUNS<-replicate(10000,simulate(tmatrix,R))

**Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities**

Clicking on "rerun with debug" in Rstudio points out the following line;

```
s.new<-sample(1:25, 1, prob=P[s, ])
```

Which is the only thing that makes sense here since it has an issue with the number of probabilities. Any ideas on how to alter this?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `s` takes any value between 1 and 25 - `sample(1:25, ....`

Hence, in order for `P[s,]` to work, it needs (at least) 25 rows. You pass this matrix to the `simulate` function. Hence, check it's dimensions

```
dim(tmatrix)
```

Comment: Hmm ok that makes sense, and the matrix I am passing has dimensions 24 X 26. I've changed the function values of 25 to 26 in the while and s.new statements. However this just yields a different error: 

"Error in R[s, s.new] : subscript out of bounds"

Comment: @user3334415: Post a reproducible example so the guessing can stop and hte coding begin.